$\lim_{s\to 0^+}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }(e^{-2^{2k}s}-e^{-2^{2k+1}s}) = \frac{1}{2}$
I have numerical evidence that
$$\lim _{s\to 0^+}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\!\left(e^{-2^{2k}s}-e^{-2^{2k+1}s}\right) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
I found out this consists of a difference between lacunary functions. However, I have no clue how to proceed or approach proving this identity.

the result is false as the high indices theorem of Hardy Littlewood shows that if the limit above exists then it would follow that $\sum a_n$ converges where $a_{2^{k}}=(-1)^k, a_n=0$ otherwise and that is patently absurd; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32542/how-can-we-prove-a-simple-case-of-the-high-indices-theorem and comments for more on this - Korevaar Tauberian Theory bible has a proof starting on page $50$

@Conrad There is a proof of the nonexistence of the limit that I discovered, which does not use Tauberian theorem, or the numerical values. Just a little bit of complex analysis is all what we need. My answer is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198665/on-an-example-of-an-eventually-oscillating-function/307432

IMHO it is worthwhile to see Noam Elkies' direct proof
on his puzzle page  https://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol8.html , as the considered series is
$S(x):=:x-x^2+x^4-x^8 +\ldots:$ with $,0<x=e^{-s}<1$ and $,0<s$.

Since there seems a bit of a confusion here, let me explain why $\lim _{s\to 0^+}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\!\left(e^{-2^{2k}s}-e^{-2^{2k+1}s}\right)$ doesn't exist due to the fact that $\sum (-1)^k$ doesn't exist. This is a Theorem of Hardy-Littlewood from $1926$ that has a surprisingly tricky proof for its heart of the argument and people tried to simplify it in various ways - today there are several approaches (and generalizations) though imho the Hardy-Littlewood original approach as clarified by Ingham in $1937$ and presented in Korevaar bible on Tauberian Theory is still the best.
First with $x=e^{-s}$ one reduces this to the analytic function on the unit disc $f(x)=\sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^kx^{2^{k}}$ which has radius of convergence $1$ so the brackets above are not necessary and one needs to show that $\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)$ doesn't exist since the sum of the coefficients doesn't converge.
The approach of Hardy-Littlewood/Ingham is real variable so only the behavior on $[0,1]$ matters with its crux being that if $F(x)=\sum a_kx^{2^{k}}$ is ANY such function which is bounded on $[0,1]$ - let's call the bound as usual $||F||_{\infty}$ - then there is a universal constant $C$ that DOES NOT depend on $F$ (just on the form of $F$ with the $2^k$ exponents) st for all the partial sums, one has $$|\sum_{k=0}^Na_kr^{2^{k}}| <C||F||_{\infty}. 0 \le r \le 1$$
The proof of this which is actually needed only for $r=1$ since otherwise it follows by considering $F(rx)$ is the tricky part and is done using a special fixed polynomial (again depending only on the $2^k$ support) which "amplifies" the gap between the $2^k$ support allowing to use crude exponential majorizations - the method is called "ramp-up" for that reason and it is fairly technical but standard in Tauberian theory since Littlewood exploited it to prove his famous Theorem on the subject.
Once this is proved everything follows easily by contradiction since if now $f(x) \to A, x \to 1^-$ it follows that $f$ extended by $A$ at $1$ is continuous hence uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ so for every $\epsilon$ there is $0<r_{\epsilon}<1$ st $||f(x)-f(rx)||_{\infty}< \epsilon, r \ge r_{\epsilon}$. Since $f(x)-f(rx)$ is of the same form as $f$ the result above applies giving that all partial sums $|\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k(1-r^{2^k})| <C\epsilon, r \ge r(\epsilon)$ and now the standard (Tauberian) three-way split $$|\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k-f(1)| \le |\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k(1-r^{2^k})|+|\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^kr^{2^k}-f(r)|+|f(r)-f(1)|$$ gives us a contradiction since on RHS the first term is at most $C\epsilon$ for all $N$ if $r$ close enough to $1$ and then we can choose such an $r$ st also $|f(r)-f(1)|<\epsilon$ and then we can choose $N(\epsilon)$ st for that fixed $r$ and all $N \ge N(\epsilon)$ the middle sum is at most $\epsilon$ giving overall $|\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k-f(1)| \le (C+2)\epsilon, N \ge N(\epsilon)$ which of course contradicts the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^N(-1)^k$ diverges.
